# How to open or view .doc, .docx ,.pdf from a url or link

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, intentfilter

How can I see or open a document in android application using url. The doc can be of any type like .doc,.docx,.pdf,.xls and etc..

Comment: public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
    setContentView(mWebView);
  }
}

Comment: you could refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724009/open-a-pdf-from-url